# Interested in editing fiction novel as co-author?

Tags: fiction, editing, collaboration

I've written a fiction novel that is intended to be the first in a series of five. I have not edited to novel and want to know if any writer is interested in giving it a read and would like to edit/interject ideas that may increase the quality of the story.
If this is an idea that you're interested in I can email you the plot and main points of the story.

Comment: I am sorry, but we are not a job board. Here are three questions with answers about how and where to find co-authors: [one question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/12777/60280), [another question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/30372/60280), [and a third](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/66616/60280). Another option is to pay an editor. Good luck!